# How to set a specific rule in Rsyslogd for an IP address and send to a mysql server

Tags: mysql, rsyslog

I'm currently using rsyslog to send all my syslogs to a SQL server and it works fine.
But one of my computer sends it to an diffrent format.
How can I set an exception for a given IP address?

Here is what I got now:

```
$template sysMysql,"INSERT INTO logs (host,facility, priority,level,tag,datetime,program,msg) VALUES('%HOSTNAME%','%syslogfacility-text%','%syslogpriority-text%','%syslogseverity%','%syslogtag%','%timereported:::date-mysql%','%programname%', '%msg%')", SQL
*.*;authpriv.none;mail.none;cron.none >127.0.0.1,centreon_syslog,centreon_syslog,*****;sysMysql
```

And I want to change that template just for one IP Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay my bad, I found something here: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903498/rsyslog-v5-log-remote-to-mysql)
But to be complete, here what I had to do:

```
$template sysMysqlUcopia,"INSERT INTO logs (host,facility, priority,level,tag,datetime,program,msg) VALUES('portailcaptif','%syslogfacility-text%','%syslogpriority-text%','%syslogseverity%','%syslogtag%','%timereported:::date-mysql%','%programname%', '%msg%')", SQL

$template sysMysql,"INSERT INTO logs (host,facility, priority,level,tag,datetime,program,msg) VALUES('%HOSTNAME%','%syslogfacility-text%','%syslogpriority-text%','%syslogseverity%','%syslogtag%','%timereported:::date-mysql%','%programname%', '%msg%')", SQL

:fromhost-ip, isequal, "172.17.97.60" >127.0.0.1,centreon_syslog,centreon_syslog,*****;sysMysqlUcopia
& ~

*.*;authpriv.none;mail.none;cron.none >127.0.0.1,centreon_syslog,centreon_syslog,*****;sysMysql
```